# How to check a given string contains only number or not in C

Tags: c

How to check a given string contains only number or not?

Comment: Go through the string, use `isdigit()`.

Comment: @H2CO3:  That was an answer not a comment - you might post it as such.

Comment: @Clifford OK, if the community won't feel I'm repwhoring (I do, anyway... :P)

Comment: Just check manual of `ctype.h`. There are many  more `is*` function

Comment: I would have answered it if @H2CO3 did not comment it. :P

Comment: Do you want to check that the string comprises only digits 0-9, or that it parses to produce a number with no whitespace etc?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: What's the difference between those two choices?  I agree that the question may not be clear, but I am not sure your counter-question is any clearer.

Comment: @Clifford `" -123.99e+22  "` can be parsed as a number, and contains only a number, but includes whitespace, punctuation, and an alphabetic character.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  Good point.  A clarification is indeed needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string has only numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41776955/2908724)

Comment: This is a great question!

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `isdigit()` macro to check if a character is a number. Using this, you can easily write a function that checks a string for containing numbers only.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int digits_only(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (isdigit(*s++) == 0) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Subminiature stylistic sidenote: returns true for the empty string. You might or might not want this behavior.

Comment: Considering the other answer so far, that was well worth posting after all ;-)

Comment: @Clifford Yeah, pretty much :P

Comment: If you don't want to use `ctype.h` and `isdigit()`, just test for `if(*s<'0' || *s>'9')`. The C-standard guarantees that `c - '0'` has the characters numeric value for any character `c` that is a digit. That is true even for Unicode character sets.

Comment: This function returns `true` for empty string.

Comment: You could change the algo to consider floats too. For example 2343.34 should also return true.

`int digits_only(const char *s)  
{  
        while (*s) {  
                if(*s == '.') {  
                        *s++;  
                        continue;  
                }  
                else if ((isdigit(*s++) == 0))  
                        return 0;  
        }  
        return 1;  
}`

Comment: `int digits_only(const char *s)
{
    if(*s == '0') return 0;
    while (*s) {
        if(*s>='0' && *s<='9'){ 
            s++;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}`

Answer (score -4):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[50];
    int i,len = 0,count = 0;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter any string:: ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
            if(str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57)    
            {
                  count++;
            }
    }
    printf("%d outoff %d numbers in a string",count,len);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `void main()` in 2013? Really? "`str[i]>=48 && str[i]<=57`" isn't exactly the right way to do that part either.

Comment: Too much superfluous (and compiler specific) code for others to criticise and down-vote see H2CO3's answer - short and to the point, with no unnecessary extras.  Also this counts the number of ASCII digit characters (in a somewhat obfuscated manner); that is not what the question is about.  Sure you could test `count != len`, but as a go/no-go test it is sufficient to stop on first non-digit character.  The "magic numbers" 48 and 57 could more intuitively be replaced with the caharacter constants `'0'` and `'9'`.

Comment: I know my dear friend but i post simple answer for the problem. And i hope this is the best solution to those who beginner of c programming