# Check if a string has only numbers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, isalpha

I'm trying to write a simple code to check if a string only has numbers in it. So far it's not working, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers[10];
    int i, correctNum = 0;

    scanf("%s", numbers);

    for(i = 0 ; i <= numbers ; ++i)
    {
        if(isalpha(numbers[i]))
        {
            correctNum = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(correctNum == 1)
    {
        printf("That number has a char in it. FIX IT.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All numbers. Good.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working"? You're not checking if everything is numeric, for starters. You're checking if there's a letter in it. You probably would rather want to use `isdigit()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Use a *positive* test with `isdigit` as you may encounter chars that are not alpha and not digits...

Comment: `char numbers[10];` is fairly small, suggest 1) `char numbers[100];`  2) `isdigit()` and 3) `scanf("%99s", numbers);`

Comment: @JoeC This is just a very small part of a significantly larger project I'm working on. I was never taught any of this in a school setting, I'm just trying to implement some extra nifty features.

Comment: `i <= numbers` is an error and your compiler should have diagnosed it. Pay attention to compiler messages.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the others answers, you can also use [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) to determine if a string has all numbers or not. It basically converts the string to an integer, and leaves out any non-integers. You can read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) for more information on this function, and the extensive error checking you can do with it.

Also, you should use:

```
scanf("%9s", numbers);
```

Instead of:

```
scanf("%s", numbers);
```

To avoid buffer overflow.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUM 10
#define BASE 10

int main(void) {
    char numbers[MAXNUM];
    char *endptr;
    int number;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%9s", numbers);

    number = strtol(numbers, &endptr, BASE);

    if (*endptr != '\0' || endptr == numbers) {
        printf("'%s' contains non-numbers\n", numbers);
    } else {
        printf("'%s' gives %d, which has all numbers\n", numbers, number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example input 1:**

```
Enter string: 1234
```

Output:

```
'1234' gives 1234, which has all numbers
```

**Example input 2:**

```
Enter string: 1234hello
```

Output:

```
'1234hello' contains non-numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [`strspn`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strspn.htm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s %s\n",
            strlen(argv[i]) == strspn(argv[i], "0123456789") ? "digits" : "mixed",
            argv[i]
        );
    }
}
```

Demoed:

```
$ ./try foo 123 ba23a 123.4
mixed foo
digits 123
mixed ba23a
mixed 123.4
```

`strspn` returns the initial number of characters from the first argument that appear in the second argument. Super simple examples:

```
strspn("abba", "a");  // == 1
strspn("abba", "b");  // == 0
strspn("abba", "ab"); // == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0 ; i <= numbers ; ++i) //how is this supposed to work.
```

Run the loop from `0` to `1` less than the `length` of the input.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(numbers) ; ++i)
```

Comment: Why not also mention that the loop guard can be `numbers[i] != '\0`. This is more C like.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers[10];
    int i, correctNum = 0;

    scanf("%s", numbers);

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i]<48||numbers[i]>57)
        {
            correctNum = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(correctNum == 1)
    {
        printf("That number has a char in it. FIX IT.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All numbers. Good.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code is not correct. For loop condition should be i<strlen(numbers) and not i<=10. Check your code for input 12345, it will give wrong output.

Comment: Sorry my bad!!! I just edited his code and forgot to remove that =. Edited it. Thanks @GAURANG
Rest is assuring.

Comment: you didnot understand. strlen(numbers) will not be 10 always. 10 here just means the maximum length  of the string to be entered. You will have to replace ' i<10 ' by ' i<strlen(numbers) '. @Shreyas

Comment: Yeah i know @Gaurang. I was just trying to give him an answer. that's it.

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in the for loop - 
for(i = 0 ; i <= numbers ; ++i)

numbers is pointer and the comparison of it with integer is forbidden.
Correct Code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   char numbers[10];
   int i, correctNum = 0;

    scanf("%s", numbers);

    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(numbers) ; ++i)
    {
       if(!(numbers[i]>='0' && numbers[i]<='9'))
       {
           correctNum = 1;
            break;
       }
    }

    if(correctNum == 1)
    {
         printf("That number has a char in it. FIX IT.\n");
     }
   else
    {
        printf("All numbers. Good.\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It would be better to use `!isdigit(numbers[i])` instead of `!(numbers[i] >= ...`

Comment: will that affect the efficiency significantly ? @linuxfan

Comment: how is isdigit() function implemented internally ? @linuxfan

Comment: it is not for efficiency, but for brevity, clarity and correctness. Anyway isdigit(), if not more efficient, surely is not less.

Comment: I also said correctness. Don't assume that C programs always run on ascii systems. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification

Comment: Thanks! It also works when the only code I change is "numbers" in the for loop to "strlen(numbers)".

Comment: Talking about efficiency: 1st of all you want to remove the call to `strlen` on a constant string out of the `for`-statement.

Comment: Why not just `numbers[i] != '\0'` as the guard?