# What do I need to change so cs50 Caesar only prints the correct message after i iterate over each character?

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I am stuck trying to iterate over each character to detect whether or not it is a digit, while only printing the answer once. The problem I'm having is I can get it to detect whether a character is a digit or not, but it prints out an answer for each number I put in until it reaches a letter. I'm looking how to get it to detect whether or not the input is a number or letter, and then make a decision on what to print out instead of printing success every time it detects a number. Feel like its something with my for loop but cant quite figure it out. Thanks.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{    
    string n = argv[1];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0, length = strlen(n); i < length; i++)
            if(!isdigit(n[i]))
            {
                printf("usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int convert = atoi(n);
                printf("Success\n");
                printf("%i\n", convert);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string has only numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776955/check-if-a-string-has-only-numbers-in-c)

Comment: Instead of `atoi` you could use `strtol` which allows you to simplify the whole `else` part of `if (argc != 2)` to 3 or 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `for` you have an if-else statement... that means that one of both will always execute for every iterarion. 
For printing success just once, you should erase the `else` keyword (and for clarity the brackets) but keeping the `else` code.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{    
    string n = argv[1];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0, length = strlen(n); i < length; i++)
        {
            if(!isdigit(n[i]))
            {
                printf("usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }         
        }
        int convert = atoi(n);
        printf("Success\n");
        printf("%i\n", convert);   
    }
}
```

Comment: @hellothere12311212 for making the code more readable, I suggest you to include the brackets of the for... I will edit it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to change so cs50 Caesar only prints the correct message after i iterate over each character?

It seems you aren't aware that you don't have to do that. The [Caesar Specification](https://docs.cs50.net/2018/x/psets/2/caesar/caesar.html#specification) says:

- You can assume that, if a user does provide a command-line argument, it will be a non-negative integer (e.g., `1`). No need to check that it’s indeed numeric.