# How to use isdigit function in C

Tags: c, function, cs50

I'm a complete beginner doing the cs50 course and I need to check if an argument from a user is a digit or not.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i = 1;
  if (isdigit(i) == 1)
    {
      printf("i is a digit");
    }
  else if (isdigit(i) == 0)
    {
      printf("i is not a digit");
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I basically get a reverse of what I should be getting. When i is a number it prints out "i is not a number" and visa versa.
What am I doing wrong? I thought isdigit returns a non-zero value if it is a digit and 0 if not. Basically 1 being true and 0 being false. Is this not correct?
Much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps some documentation would help: [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

"The isdigit function tests for any decimal-digit character".  `i` with a *value* of 1 is not a digit character.

Try `i = '1';`.  Then `i` will have the value of a digit character.

Code is testing the return value incorrectly. [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62662235/2410359).  `is...()` returns 0 or non-zero.

```
// if (isdigit(i) == 1)
if (isdigit(i))
```

Note: `is...(int ch)` functions are only valid for `ch` in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks so much I was literally stuck on this for days haha!

Comment: @UKushi `isstuck(U_Kushi("2020/06/30")) --> false`

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the documentation for `isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) you'll note the return value is expressed as:

> Non-zero value if the character is a numeric character, zero otherwise.

In other words, don't compare to exactly one, that's not assured. Compare to **non-zero**.

That being said, this works on *characters* not *integers*, although in C the line is blurred. What you want is to ensure this is part of a string, like:

```
char* n = "12345";

if (isdigit(n[0]) == 0) {
  ...
}
```

In your case you're asking if ASCII character 1 is a digit, which it is not. That's the "Start of Heading" (SOH) control character.

Comment: right got it, thanks! Basically I'm trying to make sure that argv[1][i] are all digits

Comment: There's an [answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776955/check-if-a-string-has-only-numbers-in-c) if that's your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

[`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) is a [*character* classification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) function.

It will return zero or non-zero depending on if a *character* (or rather, a character [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int`) is a digit.

For example:

```
int i = '1';  // Initialize to the character '1'
if (isdigit(i))
  {
    printf("i is a digit");
  }
else
  {
    printf("i is not a digit");
  }
```

Note that `isdigit` returns a *non-zero* value for digit characters, it doesn't have to be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `isdigit` should be a single character, not a number. Thus your test code should more properly be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
  {
  char c = '1';

  if(isdigit(c))
    printf("c is a digit");
  else
    printf("c is not a digit");

  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should stick to the definition of the function, and not make assumptions about the returned value if it is a digit - the actual returned value may be implementation dependent, here's a better C-style, though as others have have said, you should be passing in a char, not an int - did the compiler not complain about that?

```
if (isdigit(i)) {
  printf("i is a digit");
} else {
  printf("i is not a digit");
}
```